# Using "this"(MainWindow.xaml.cs) in another Class

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have two methods:

Method 1(Class 1):

```
private void bntStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CreateMap gogo = new CreateMap();
    gogo.doWork(ref this);//.xaml.cs//window
}
```

Method 2(Class 2)(different file than "MainWindow.xaml.cs") :

```
public void doWork(ref Window instance)
{

}
```

I would like to use "instance", as if I where in my "MainWIndow.xaml.cs" just get the reference the mainWindow.

By the way is it not possible because of the dispatcher(Ui-Thread), only one is allowed...Or I am wrong !?

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

**You should NOT do this**

You can just put this into MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public static MainWindow Instance { get; private set;}

public MainWindow()
{
    Instance = this;
}
```

Or use something like:

```
(MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

**However**, your views should be totally self contained. There are *way* better ways to get data/commands to them (via proper use of MVVM).

Comment: I see no harm in that, what would be the problem ?

Comment: @user254197 The problem is that this whole thing is an awful design.

Comment: Ok, and if I would just pass a panel(or single ui-element) reference (s) instead of the entire window, this would also be bad right ? And by the way, if I use it the way you wrote I have no access to the elements on my window, which I already created. In my Main I just used :"this.pnl.." but in my Class2 I can not access anymore(private Window mainWindowReferenz; mainWindowReferenz.pnl...";)... What to do ?

Comment: @user254197 Yeah, because thats a private member, *and it should be*. Just stop now, and rethink this whole thing so you don't just cause yourself more pain. You could expose it via a public property, but just don't.